# where does rails' "rake assets:precompile" source code live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

Can't find it in [railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks)

Can only find part of it in [sprocketstask](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb)

Where to look?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rake task itself is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb) in `sprokets-rails` gem.

Answer (score 5):

In rails 3.2.6 you can find it with `gem contents actionpack | grep rake`

Comment: why not tell us the result of that grep, where it's actually defined, instead of making all readers download the source and run it for themselves?

Comment: It's defined here in Rails 3.2 -> https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake#L28 cheers to the answerer for pointing me in the direction of actionpack.